# Insert i18n language into the request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, python-3.x, django, i18next

I'm using the i18next lib, together with react in my front, and i intend to pass the information of my current language to my api through every request.

I have a axios client wrapped in a constant that i use in my whole application, like this:
`

```
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: CONSTANTS.API.BASE,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  timeout: TIME_OUT,
});
```

`

I'd like to know if there some easy way to do this, and then get the language information in the back.
By the way, i'm using Django REST Framework in my api.

I tried to simply declare a variable into the headers in the client, just for test, but  i couldn't get the value in the request in the api

Comment: With i18next you can store the language in a cookie, it will be sent with all request

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how server handles language header but you have to send it to the server same way you are sending Content-Type.

Here is an example of using Spring boot (default policy detect language by request header Accept-Language) and axios. In the example, I am creating new axios instance. If you do not create new one, you can set default on existing instance almost the same way. See axios docs.

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: readEnv("URL_ENV_VAR"),
    headers: {
        "Accept-Language": i18n.language,
    },
});
```

Also be aware of value in i18n.language. I have come across several browsers which gave me different values so always send expected value to the server.